# Get fontSize from span element

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm trying to get access to my span elements font size.

I have a bunch of span elements inside a div.  I change the font size depending on the screen size using a stylesheet. I want to add it to the canvas, but it needs to have the same font/font size.  Lets say in my CSS I have `span{font-size:12px}`

```
let spanEl = document.getElementsByTagName("span")
let canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas")
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

ctx.font = spanEl.fontSize+" "+"Open Sans";
```

When I do `console.log(ctx.font)` it returns `10px san-serif` which I guess is the default font for the canvas.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `document.getElementsByTagName` returns a list of elements, and not one. Because of that you can't access the font size of that list.
2. The second problem you have is that the `fontSize` is not a parameter of the element, but a property of the `style` parameter.
3. The third problem is that `fontSize` might be set in the `css` and not in the `style` attribute of that specific `span` element you just accessed.

What you can do is the following:

```
let spanEl = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
ctx.font = window.getComputedStyle(spanEl[0]).fontSize + " Open Sans";
```

Check the following example:

```js
let spanEl = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(spanEl[0]).fontSize);
```

```css
span {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<span>test</span><br />
<span>test</span><br />
<span>test</span><br />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.getComputedStyle` in-order to calculate the fontSize of the span.

```js
let spanEl = document.getElementsByTagName("span");

console.log(window.getComputedStyle(spanEl[0]).fontSize)
```

```css
span {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<span>Text here</span>
```